# SCSS formatting in Netbeans on a Mac?

Tags: macos, netbeans, sass

I'm using Netbeans 7.3.1 on a Macbook Pro with OS X 10.8.3.

I've installed the [SCSS plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/34929).  Until now, I've been using Windows (Mac is new to me), and the SCSS plugin worked fine on Netbeans and was able to auto-indent and format my SCSS files.

Now that I'm using Netbeans on a Mac, this plugin doens't seem to do the formatting.

I go to Source > Format (or CTRL-Shift-F), and the code spacing doesn't change.

Comment: I noticed an alert in the bottom right of Netbeans and found out that this bug has been reported (https://github.com/jmarsault/scss-editor/issues/19) to the plugin creator.  If anyone knows a fix or a quick workaround, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try 7.4 Beta with new support for editing and compiling Scss/Less files. Download link is on netbeans.org